# Loss of precision during a for loop [arrays]

Tags: java

```
double [] temperature = new double[length];    
// After this, the doubles are added to the array after being read from a file.    
for (int i : temperature) 
{
    System.out.printf("%5s" , i.toString());
}
```

During the for loop, I get the error "possible loss of precision required int; found: double"
around the 'temperature' part of the loop. How can I create a for loop to print the values of the doubles in this string?

Comment: Use a `double` instead of an `int`?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
for(int i : temperature)
```

to

```
for(double i : temperature)
```

Note that `temperature` is an array of `double`s and not `int`s.

How does your code compile? Are you sure `i.toString()` gives you no errors? It's enough to print `i`.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that the int in the beginning was for 'I', not for the array.

Comment: @user3236383 Well, it is. The array is a `double` array and remains one. But when you make `i` an `int` and fetch the doubles out of the array and into `i`, you truncate everything after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
for (double i : temperature)
```

Comment: This still won't compile.  He needs one other change too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is that your array is full of doubles and you're treating them as ints. Say something like `for(double i:temperature)` instead.

Comment: This still won't compile.  He needs one other change too.

Comment: @DavidWallace I know that it doesn't solve the toString() issue, but it does solve the problem he asked about.

Comment: No.  His question was "How can I create a for loop to print the values of the doubles in this string?".  This answer won't do that for him.  I should really be downvoting this (and Kevin's answer too), but I'm in a good mood today!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping the temperatures as a `double` throughout, rather than converting them to `int`.  Also, instead of using `toString()` to convert, you could specify in the format string how to format the `double`.  For example, if you want the `double` values printed to two decimal places, you could write

```
for (double eachTemperature : temperature) {
    System.out.format("%.2f%n", eachTemperature);
}
```

More information about the different format strings you can use is at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html